# javascript navigator.appName and userAgent not giving what I want

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

I'm totally new and just started `javascript` and playing around with the basic `alert()`

I'm wondering how are we able to check what `browser` is being used?
All are navigator object doesn't seem to give out what is wanted.  If I use `appName` it gives me out `Netscape` in everything and I believe all know that.

Is there a way I can make the `alert();` to check and show either just `IE`, `Firefox`, `Chrome`, something like that?

If using `userAgent`, it gives out too much info...

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you shouldn't be trying to do *browser detection*, that being said, all browsers choose to implement both the `userAgent` and the `appName` however they want.

To correct this, you should try the following code

```
   var BrowserDetect = {
    init: function () {
        this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
        this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
            || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
            || "an unknown version";
        this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
    },
    searchString: function (data) {
        for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            var dataString = data[i].string;
            var dataProp = data[i].prop;
            this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
            if (dataString) {
                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                    return data[i].identity;
            }
            else if (dataProp)
                return data[i].identity;
        }
    },
    searchVersion: function (dataString) {
        var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
        if (index == -1) return;
        return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length+1));
    },
    dataBrowser: [
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Chrome",
            identity: "Chrome"
        },
        {   string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "OmniWeb",
            versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
            identity: "OmniWeb"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Apple",
            identity: "Safari",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            prop: window.opera,
            identity: "Opera",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "iCab",
            identity: "iCab"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "KDE",
            identity: "Konqueror"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Firefox",
            identity: "Firefox"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Camino",
            identity: "Camino"
        },
        {       // for newer Netscapes (6+)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Netscape",
            identity: "Netscape"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "MSIE",
            identity: "Explorer",
            versionSearch: "MSIE"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Gecko",
            identity: "Mozilla",
            versionSearch: "rv"
        },
        {       // for older Netscapes (4-)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Mozilla",
            identity: "Netscape",
            versionSearch: "Mozilla"
        }
    ],
    dataOS : [
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Win",
            identity: "Windows"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Mac",
            identity: "Mac"
        },
        {
               string: navigator.userAgent,
               subString: "iPhone",
               identity: "iPhone/iPod"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Linux",
            identity: "Linux"
        }
    ]

};
BrowserDetect.init();
```

This code was taken from [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) by the way.

To use this code you can just do the following

```
var version = BrowserDetect.version;
var OS = BBrowserDetect.OS;
var browser = BBrowserDetect.browser;
```

Comment: wow O.o I just like...started javascript...like...totally basics only...this this....>.<"

Comment: Welcome to our world. It is because you are trying to detect the inconsistencies between the different browsers implementation of JavaScript.

Comment: >.<" I don't think my instructor wants me to put those codes from quirksmode haha. Maybe I'll just stay with the basic userAgent and see what he says :P

Comment: is it because nescape created javascript or something? >.<"

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
if( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1){
   // Google chrome
}
else if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1){
   // Firefox.
}
else if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') > -1){
   // MSIE
}
else if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') > -1){
   // Safari
}
```